# ASP.NET over menu

Tags: javascript

How to open menu when mouse is over the image?

Where can I find a tutorial, source, etc.?

Comment: There are several solutions to this.  Which platform are you building for (.Net, php, ?)  .Net has a user control for emitting menus.  If using a language like php, then you need to look at some of the dhtml menu systems out there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the right topic for you:

[Adding MouseOver Images to the ASP.NET 2.0 Menu Control](http://blogs.inetium.com/blogs/jcleath/archive/2006/08/10/301.aspx)